How does the child process signal completion of execution?
Here is the host program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        printf("Starting the main function.\n");
        int retval=1;
        pid_t pid=fork();

        if (pid==0)
        {
                printf("In the child process now. The PID of the child is %d and the PID of its parent is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
                printf("Child process now, retval is %d\n", retval);
                execl("./binsearch", argv[1], NULL);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Back to the parent process now, here is its PID: %d.\n", getpid());
                printf("Parent process now, retval is %d\n", retval);

                wait(&retval);
                if(WIFEXITED(retval)==1)
                {
                        printf("Process terminated normally.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Process termniated abnormally.\n");
                        exit(42);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}

Here is the program with its executable as ./binsearch:
#include <stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
    if (r >= l) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == x)
            return 1;
        if (arr[mid] > x)
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
    }
    return -1;
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void sort(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, key, arr[10];
    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("Enter the elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    sort(arr, n);
    
    printf("Enter element to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    
    int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, key);
    if (result == -1) {
        printf("Element is not present in array\n");
    } else {
        printf("Element is present\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Here is the output when I execute the host program:
Starting the main function.
Back to the parent process now, here is its PID: 1734.
Parent process now, retval is 1
In the child process now. The PID of the child is 1735 and the PID of its parent is 1734.
Child process now, retval is 1
Enter the number of elements in the array: 3
Enter the elements: 1 2 3
Enter element to be searched: 2
Element is present
Process terminated normally.

I cannot understand the sequence of instructions being executed here. After the first line, Starting the main function. why does the else block of the parent process execute? Shouldn't the child process execute since the fork call was the next instruction?
Also, how does retval reflect the completion of the child process in teh else block of the host program? As far as I can make out, it is a binary sempahore which the child process acquires when it starts executing and releases when it finishes. However, I can't make out how any of this is done by the child process.

Please take some time to read the wait manual page. The WIFEXITED doesn't return the child process exit code, it just checks if the child has terminated normally (its result may be different than 1). You need to use the WEXITSTATUS macro to get the actual exit code.

@Someprogrammerdude I get that WIFEXITED only indicates the status of execution, but please help me understand why we are passing retval as an argument to WIFEXITED.

The values set by wait depends on how the child process terminated. It's mostly a set of single bits, with only the low eight bits spared for the actual process return value (what it passes to exit or return from the main function). The macros help check the correct bits (which are not specified) and help to extract the exit value (if one exist).

A process can also exit with a status such that WIFSIGNALED(retval) returns true, in which case you can use WTERMSIG(retval) to get the signal number that exited the process.  Note that EXIT_SUCCESS is normally 0 and EXIT_FAILURE is normally 1.  These values are passed to exit() or the return statement that finishes main().  And as already noted, printing WEXITSTATUS(retval) will show the actual exit status (if the child exited normally).  It's usually a good idea to use wait() in a loop, capturing and testing the child PID, just in case there's a problem.

The fork function, as most tutorials and books say, "returns twice".
It returns one time in the child process, with the return value 0. And it returns one time in the parent process, with the pid of the child process.
From the point that fork returns, you have two independent processes, both running simultaneously.
But you also have no control over which process will continue first; it's up to the operating system.
In your case it seems that the parent process continues to run, until it gets to the wait call. That call will then wait for the first (or in your case only) child-process to exit. And only then resume running.
While the parent process is stuck in the wait call, the child process can run all the way to finish. At which point, it will no longer exist, and the OS will continue the parent process by returning from its wait call.
